# can't update boolean mongoose object with a time stamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having trouble updating a boolean object and i am getting error every time-

this is the object-

```
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    
    const PlantProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    
      waterMotor: {
        state: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false,
          time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
        }
      },
    
    });


module.exports = mongoose.model('PlantProduct', PlantProductSchema);
```

this is the update action-

```
      plantProduct.waterMotor.update({state: idResultsObj.motorState });
```

idResultsObj.motorStat is boolean i chacked

on the other hand when I change I do this -

```
plantProduct.waterMotor.state = idResultsObj.motorState;
```

it works but It doesn't give a time stamp.

I appreciate any help I get!!

Comment: look at the correct syntax of [update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) method.

Comment: can you provide more details regarding your schema? @yaron k

Comment: i add to the schema.

Comment: also, please add the error which you are getting. @yaronk

Comment: Errore:undefined

Answer (score 0):

you are not using the update function correctly. it accepts two arguments, the first is the document to be updated and the second is the action.

you need to pass the id (or any other field like username) of the document that is being updated as the first argument.

```
plantProduct.waterMotor.update({_id: id},  {state: idResultsObj.motorState });
```

Comment: I have found the object PlantProductthat i want to change. 
but even if  i do:
 `const PlantProduct = require('../../models/PlantProduct');
PlantProduct.waterMotor.update({ _id: plantProduct._id }, { state: idResultsObj.motorState });`
I am still getting Errore: undefined

Comment: I tried to fellow  and did this from [mongoos](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.updateOne) -
    `const res = await PlantProduct.waterMotor.updateOne({ _id: plantProduct._id }, { state: idResultsObj.motorState });
      console.log(res)`
still i am getting the same ERROR @A R, @rohanraj

Answer (score 0):

These are a couple of API which [mongoose support](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html) for an update operation.
Regarding your code you have used [update](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.update) in the wrong way. `update` is the property of the `Model` object that why you are getting `undefined`.  thought said below is the query that might help you.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PlantProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  waterMotor: {
    state: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
      time: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      },
    }
  },
});


const ProductModel = mongoose.model('PlantProduct', PlantProductSchema);

const filterQuery = {}
const updateQuery = {
  $set: {
    "waterMotor.state": true
  }
}

ProductModel.update(filterQuery, updateQuery, function(error, result) {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error)
  } else {
    console.log(response)
  }
})
```